# Optimizing ranges in R

Tags: r, optimization

I have the following problem and don't know how to code it in R:

A dataframe `df` with two columns: First column an ordered set of numbers `df$ind`, the second column a highly stochastic set of numbers `df$ret`.

I want to find two ranges in `df$ret` that don't overlap and optimize the condition that the sum of the numbers in the first range must be positive and the sum of the numbers of second range negative. After that I would like to have the 2x2 `df$ind`-values of the respective ranges.

Two possibilites come to my mind (and I don't know how to program either of these in R):

1. Monte Carlo where 2x2 positions are being chosen, the sums being calculated and compared to the hitherto best solution.
2. Trying all possible ranges and taking the best solution (concerning the number of values this seems computationally doable).

Could you give me some hints how to realize this in R or is there even a package for these kinds of optimizations (there seems to be a package for everything in R ;-)

**UPDATE:**
You will have 4 values: `i`, `k`, `m`, `n`: `df$ret[i:k]` and `df$ret[m:n]` with `i` < `k` < `m` < `n`.

The optimization is (pseudocode):

> max:abs(sum(range(i:k)))+abs(sum(range(m:n)))

under the conditions:

> sum(range(i:k)) > 0 and sum(range(m:n)) < 0

Comment: Optimisation is when you can compare numbers and pick the highest or the lowest. Suppose we find two solutions, i.e. two range pairs, satisfying your conditions. It is not clear which one you prefer more.

Comment: For the first range pick the positive numbers, for the second negative.

Comment: @mpiktas: The optimization criterion would be: The bigger the sum of the first and the smaller the sum of the second range. You can take the biggest and smallest from each solution. In case that there is an overlap then choose the one that has the biggest absolute value. I don't understand you second comment because you must take the sum of the whole range, you can not cherry-pick certain values out of "ret".

Comment: By range, you mean indexes? I.e. range would be `df$ret[i+1:k]` for some values of `i` and `k`?

Comment: Still there are problems with your clarification. In optimisation you input some parameters (ranges in your case) and get *one* value. In your case you input 2 ranges (not a problem) and you get two values.

Comment: Exactly: You will have 4 values: `i`, `k`, `m`, `n`: `df$ret[i:k]` and `df$ret[m:n]` with `i` < `k` < `m` < `n`. The optimization is (pseudocode): max:abs(sum(range(i:k)))+abs(sum(range(m:n))) under the conditions: sum(range(i:k)) > 0 and sum(range(m:n)) < 0

Comment: vonjd, ok now it is clear. It would be great if you updated the question, I think it would help in getting an answer.

Comment: It's a great simplification to observe you may assume m=k+1.  If not, consider the sum of elements k+1 through m-1: if the sum is positive, include these elements in the first range; if negative, include them in the second; if zero, include them in either one.  The objective never decreases, QED.  Having said this, I am voting to close this question because although it's interesting, it's off-topic on CV.

Comment: @whuber: Nice thought! I wondered why the two ranges were always right next to each other in my testing...  A good reminder to always think before coding.

Comment: @Aaron When you reformulate the question in terms of cumulative sums of the data, observations like the one I made become obvious.  (You're trying to find a rise followed by a fall and you're optimizing the total rise plus the total fall.)  This (I hope) makes it clear how to speed up the algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a brute force method.  For small data sets it should work fine; on my system I tested with size 100 and it was on the order of 0.5 seconds.  For increased speed one should check the best max and min for overlap before checking all possible max/min pairs.

```
getbest <- function(x) {
  # get the sums of all possible ranges
  n <- length(x)
  m <- as.data.frame(t(combn(n, 2)))
  names(m) <- c("lo","hi")
  m$sum <- sapply(1:nrow(m), function(i) {
    sum(x[m$lo[i]:m$hi[i]])
  })
  # then get the ranges of positive and negative sums that don't overlap
  neg <- m[m$sum<0,]
  pos <- m[m$sum>0,]
  use <- expand.grid(neg=1:nrow(neg), pos=1:nrow(pos))
  use <- use[(neg$hi[use$neg] < pos$lo[use$pos]) | 
                  (neg$lo[use$neg] > pos$hi[use$pos]),]
  # finally get the absolute value for all ranges that don't overlap,
  # and choose the largest
  abs <- pos$sum[use$pos] - neg$sum[use$neg]
  use <- use[which.max(abs),]
  as.matrix(rbind(positive=pos[use$pos,], negative=neg[use$neg,]))
}
```

Use as follows; it returns the actual index of the range, so if the desired index `df$ind` is different than `1:n`, just use this output to get the desired values.

```
x <- rnorm(100)
getbest(x)
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast! Thank you, I tested it a few times and it seems to work fine! I will try it on my real world data now.

Comment: I tried to understand the logic of the code. Could I ask you to add some additional explanations or some comments? That would be very helpful! Thank you again!

Comment: I added a few basic comments, but a better algorithm would be to follow @whuber's suggestions.

Comment: Just noticed that the above algorithm only allows for ranges of width 2 or more; that is, `i < k` and `m < n`, as in the original post; however, it seems to me that `i <= k` and `m <= n` would be desired so that a range could include only a single number.

Comment: Yes, but that is not desirable since the data are very noisy. One outlier would than constitute a whole range - not good. Preferably seems to be the possibility of defining some min. length.

Comment: Another thought: Wouldn't it be computationally more efficient to only compute the sums over all non-overlapping series? That would mean swapping the two steps.

Comment: Actually, no, because the set of all non-overlapping series includes all possible sums, so you wouldn't gain anything.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is the topic of column 7 in Jon Bentleys celebrated "Programming Pearls". The solution is an algorithm with a run time of O(n), where n is the length of the vector x.

An R implementation can solve a vector of millions of elements in less than 3 seconds:

```
x <- rnorm(1e6)
system.time(m <- maxsub(x))
```

If you want the negative sums, too, call maxsub(-x). It's easy to change the code such that the function will return the indices. The two ranges cannot overlap, but one can be a part of the other.

```
maxsub <- function(x) {
    if (!is.numeric(x))
        stop("Argument 'x' must be a numeric vector.")

    m1 <- m2 <- 0.0
    for (i in 1:length(x)) {
        m2 <- max(m2 + x[i], 0.0)
        m1 <- max(m1, m2)
    }
    return(m1)
}
```

Though the code looks so simple, it took quite a long time until someone came up with this solution, as Bentley reports. A corresponding algorithm for the two-(or higher)dimensional case has not yet been found.

Update: Here is a version that also returns the indices. It looks complicated, but is not. It simply keeps track of the indices in each of the two steps above.

```
maxsub <- function(x, inds = FALSE) {
    if (!is.numeric(x))
        stop("Argument 'x' must be a numeric vector.")
    n <- length(x)

    if (!inds) {
        m1 <- m2 <- 0.0
        for (i in 1:n) {
            m2 <- max(m2 + x[i], 0.0)
            m1 <- max(m1, m2)
        }
        return(m1)

    } else {
        m1 <- m2 <- 0
        p1 <- p2 <- 0
        q1 <- q2 <- 1

        for (i in 1:n) {
            if (m2 > -x[i]) {
                m2 <- m2 + x[i]
                q2 <- i
                if (m2 > m1) {
                    m1 <- m2
                    p1 <- q1; p2 <- q2
                }
            } else {
                m2 <- 0
                q1 <- q2 <- i+1
            }
        }

        return(list(sum = m1, inds = c(p1, p2)))
    }
}
```

A Fortran version bounded to an R package does solve a million elements in 0.015 secs.

Comment: Thanks for the reference.  Any ideas about what to do about the potential inclusion of one range in the other?

Comment: @Hans: I have to say I don't yet fully understand the underlying logic - could you perhaps give the necessary modifications for returning the indices, that will make things clearer, I hope. Thank you for sharing this obviously highly efficient and elegant algorithm!

Comment: ...BTW: I think it is column 8, not 7.

Comment: @vonjd: I have added a version that returns the indices. To understand the algorithm it's better to look at the four lines at the beginning. Or read column 7, "Algorithm Design Techniques" (in my version of the "Programming Pearls"), or 8 (your version?) --- it is absolutely worth it.